Reassigning to struct that contains a reference
I'm trying to make a class that's a handler for messaging with a certain state.
When a message is prepared, I expect to create a new state_t struct referring to the new y data. I want to then be able to access the new object via the same state variable.
A minimal example with pointers would be something like this:
class Handler {
  int x;  // something config for the handler
  struct state_t {
    int *y;
    state_t(int *y) : y(y) {}
  };

  std::optional<state_t> state;

  Handler(int x) : x(x), state(std::nullopt) {}

  void prepare_message(int *y) {
    state = state_t(y);
  }

  void handle_state() {
    // do something with the y e.g. send it over a socket
  }

};

I was wondering if there's a good way to make this work with a reference instead of a pointer to y. Replacing it directly wouldn't compile because copy assignment is implicitly removed. Can this be overcome in an elegant way?

What are you trying to solve/gain by using a reference rather than a (raw or smart) pointer?

The first question to ask might be, who is responsible for making sure that the pointer continues to point to a valid int for as long as it's needed?

A reference can't be reseated. If you need that, you can use std::reference_wrapper instead.

Also, one of the features of a reference is it can't be null.  So if state_t held a reference instead of a pointer, then what would you want your constructor to do with it?

@Mat I was more thinking along the lines that if I only need to access the data and not to the address then a reference if more suited in some sense.

@NateEldredge I'm not sure of the proper terminology but let's say I had a vector<state_t> instead. Then same effect could be achieved by popping the old state and pushing a new one.

"because copy assignment is implicitly removed" -- In other words, it falls on you to define what should happen in copy assignment. If you have a state_t object whose y member is bound to one int, and you assign to it a state_t object whose y member is bound to a different int, then what is the behavior you expect?

It's possible that you don't need copy assignment, but since you're focused on your current solution instead of the real problem you are trying to solve, it's tough to be sure. What is the effect / functionality that you want to achieve? Or to put it another way, when you write "a good way to make this work", what constitutes working?

@JaMiT I expect the behaviour to be creating a new struct with a new reference contained within it. I want to then be able to access the new object via the same variable.

@MateriaGravis Information in comments is not part of the question. Please check that I preserved your intent when I [edit]ed your information into your question. Also, note that assignment does not create a new struct, so you appear to be not using the right tool for the job (hence you ran into an obstacle).

@RemyLebeau I had a look at the docs and that does indeed work. Thank you.

Easy enough to add a copy assignment. At least in c++20 or greater, The bigger problem is that you can't have a null reference. They have to refer to some other existing object.

You'd need your prepare_message function to look like: void prepare_message(int& y) { state.emplace(y); }

As @RemyLebeau commented, you can use std::reference_wrapper.
As you can see it does exactly what you require:

std::reference_wrapper is a class template that wraps a reference in a copyable, assignable object.

This is demonstrated below.
Note that I added a public test() method to show that state_t is now copyable/assignable (although the fact that prepare_message compiles also implies that).
I also made the constructor of Handler public in order to create it from main.
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Handler {
    [[maybe_unused]] int x;  // something config for the handler
    struct state_t {
//------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv--------
        std::reference_wrapper<int> y;
        state_t(int & y) : y(y) {}
    };

    std::optional<state_t> state;

    void prepare_message(int & y) {
        state = state_t(y);
    }

    void handle_state() {
    }

public:
    Handler(int x) : x(x), state(std::nullopt) {}
    
    // Demonstration that `state_t` is now copyable:
    void test() {
        int x1 = 1;
        int x2 = 2;
        state_t s1{ x1 };
        state_t s2{ x2 };
        std::cout << s1.y << "\n";
        s1 = s2;
        std::cout << s1.y << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Handler h{ 5 };
    h.test();
}

Output:
1
2

Live demo

Two parts of the question do not match.

I expect to create a new state_t struct

and

Replacing it directly wouldn't compile because copy assignment is implicitly removed.

Assignment does not create a new object; it overwrites an existing one. You do end up creating a new state_t object to copy from, but it's temporary. Try making your code better match your goal. Instead of copying/moving a temporary struct, construct a new one directly in the optional. That is, change
state = state_t(y); // Overwrite the `state_t` object in `state`
                    // (or move-construct one if the optional is empty).

to
state.emplace(y); // Create a new `state_t` object in `state`.
                  // (If there was already an object, it is destroyed.)

This compiles whether y is a pointer or a reference.
If your real code does actually require assignment somewhere, this change would be insufficient (use another approach, such as the other answer). However, if the simplified code in the question accurately represents your situation, then this change might be all you need.
